# navigate to a different page on a selected dates submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

i made the code bellow that describes a booking calendar , i want that when i press submit it will go to a different page by navigate. the function should check if the start date is bigger than Now and the end date is bigger then start date- when true --> navigate to a different page.

thanks in advance you guys

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-center">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <h4 class="red">Start Date</h4>
          <input name="start" type="date" class="form-control " placeholder="Start date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <h4 class="red">End Date</h4>
          <input name="end" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="End date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2">
          <input id="btnOpen" class="btn btn1 btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="container" >
  <div class="row-center">
      <div class="jumbotron">
   <div  class="row">
<div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"> 
  <h4 class="red" >Start Date</h4> 
  <input name="start" type="date" class="form-control " placeholder="Start date" > 
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"> 
  <h4 class="red">End Date</h4> 
  <input name="end" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="End date" > 
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2"> 
  <input  id="btnOpen" class="btn btn1 btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Please never put code in comments - just edit your post to include the code.  Also, what have you tried so far?  What about the code you posted isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

In your example I don't find any method that should trigger on click.

Assuming you don't know how to do it I am giving answer.

change your html like this.

```
<input id="btnOpen" class="btn btn1 btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="submitClicked()">
```

In your .ts file you have to create a function that will be triggered on button click event. Here the method name is `submitClicked()`.
so, the code will be something like this.

```
submitClicked() {
  //here you will write the logic what should this function do when the submit is clicked
  // you will need something like this
  if(todayDate > start && todayDate < end){
    //navigate to another page
  }
}
```

If you don't know **how to compare dates** or **how to navigate in another page** google it, you will find a lot of resource.

As the question is not clear enough and you are new I am just breaking the parts to make you understand how it should work so that you can now carry on you own.

Comment: Hey first of all thank you for responding quickly ! Second , I’m having trouble calling the dates from the HTML to my function logic , I know how to compare but I tried a few things and I’m probably missing something.. can you please tell me how would u create the variables , how do u call the dates from the HTML ?

Comment: actually I am confused what you are asking. do you know about data binding in angular? you need to use NgModel to bind data. suppose you update the value in html input and you need to get the value in ts or js. here the data bindings come. so when user change the value, you will get the value in ts and use it.